# GeoJSON custom marker for different data sources

Tags: leaflet, geojson, java, markers, php

I need help how to show markers with two different colors for two different GeoJSON data sources.

Here's first source geojson.php:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    null,
                    null
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                
                "Idpel": null,
                "Rayon": null,
                "Daya": null,
                "Alamat Lengkap": null,
                "Date": null,
                "Keterangan": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's second source geojsonpl.php

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[]}
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Map Panel & Lampu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<?php $id=$_GET['id']; ?>
    <div id="map"></div>
<script src="leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
<script src="spin.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet.spin.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var m= L.map('map').setView([-5.1478036504745255,119.42012756104154], 13);
var mopt = {
    url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicnlhbjkzc3AiLCJhIjoiY2pkMDJxZ2xpMGxjYTJxbzRtd3EzZnRzcCJ9.WsRQpljGbYjxw7za2_cPtA',
    options: {attribution:' © <a href="#">#</a>'}
  };
var mq=L.tileLayer(mopt.url,mopt.options);

mq.addTo(m);


function popUp(f,l){
    var out = [];
    if (f.properties){
        for(key in f.properties){
            out.push(key+": "+f.properties[key]);
        }
        l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
    }
}
var jsonTest = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["geojson.php?idpanel=<?php echo $id; ?>","geojsonpl.php?idpanel=<?php echo $id; ?>"],{onEachFeature:popUp}).addTo(m);
```

I want the marker/color to be different from the others, like this the blue color (panel) change with the red color, etc.

Comment: How would you decide which of those two icons should be use for a specific marker?

Comment: I chose geojson.php as the specifier for

Comment: This does not answer the question. GeoJSON has a lot of properties/data. Please describe exactly on the basis of which data/value you would choose the marker.

Comment: I, m sorry. I mean this data 
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    null,
                    null
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                
                "Idpel": null,
                "Rayon": null,
                "Daya": null,
                "Alamat Lengkap": null,
                "Date": null,
                "Keterangan": null
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Which of those properties determines the marker color?

Comment: Please edit your question and add explanation from your last comment to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet has only one standard blue icon for markers, so if you want to have markers with different icons, you'll have to create them yourself (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#icon).

Since you have two different GeoJSON layer sources and want to have different markers for each source, the simplest way is to create two separate layers, where you assign custom markers with desired icon to each layer via `pointToLayer` option.

Code could then look something like this:

```js
var icon1 = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'icon_image_path/icon1.png',
  iconSize: [32, 37],
  iconAnchor: [16, 37],
  popupAnchor: [0, -28]
});

var icon2 = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'icon_image_path/icon2.png',
  iconSize: [32, 37],
  iconAnchor: [16, 37],
  popupAnchor: [0, -28]
});

var jsonTest1 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("geojson.php?idpanel=<?php echo $id; ?>",{
  pointToLayer: function(point, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon1});
  },
  onEachFeature: popUp
}).addTo(m);

var jsonTest2 = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("geojsonpl.php?idpanel=<?php echo $id; ?>",{
  pointToLayer: function(point, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon2});
  },
  onEachFeature: popUp
}).addTo(m);
```